# Changing background of two TextView alternativly

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two TextViews placed side by side horizontally and they are in a rectangle shape with rounded corners.

**I would like:**

1. to change the background which is by default *none* to *white* when
   pressed or clicked and back to *default* when the second TextView is
   clicked or pressed,
2. the padding which is between the shape and the text to be *white* when pressed and back to *default* when the other is selected
3. the Textcolor to go *black* when the background goes *white*

**Xml code of the the two TextViews:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle"
    android:id="@+id/l1"
    >

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Coach"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"
       android:id="@+id/TV"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Client"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/TV1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

_____Java Code________

```
package com.example.jhang.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.R.color.black;
import static android.R.color.white;

/**
* Created by jhang on 5/2/2016.
*/
public class Activity1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView coach, client, about, privacy, faq, contact,login;
LinearLayout l1;
int count=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    coach=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV);
    client=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV1);
    about=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV2);
    privacy=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV3);
    faq=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV4);
    contact=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV5);
    login=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.button);
    l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l1);

    coach.setOnClickListener(this);
    client.setOnClickListener(this);
    about.setOnClickListener(this);
    privacy.setOnClickListener(this);
    faq.setOnClickListener(this);
    contact.setOnClickListener(this);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
    l1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{


    if (count==0)
    {
        coach.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        coach.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        count=1;
    }
   else if (count==1)
    {
        client.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        client.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        count=0;
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Show what you have done so far

Comment: can you show your java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View v)
{


if (count==0)
{

    client.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    client.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    coach.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    coach.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    count=1;
}
   else if (count==1)
{

    coach.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    coach.setTextColor(Color.White);

    client.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    client.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    count=0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way ,create this xml button_press

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/blue" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

</shape>
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_press"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Press 1" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_press"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Press 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
Textview button;

public void onClick(View v) {

    Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_press);
    dr.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn:

        if (button == null) {
            button = (TextView ) findViewById(v.getId());
        } else {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_press);
            button = (TextView ) findViewById(v.getId());
        }
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);

        break;

    case R.id.btn2:
        if (button == null) {
            button = (TextView ) findViewById(v.getId());
        } else {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_press);
            button = (TextView ) findViewById(v.getId());
        }
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```